# Linux Audit Server Reboots

Tags: linux, centos, auditd

I'm running AuditD on Centos 6.5.

**Is there a way to audit server reboots** - who and when a server is rebooted? So if I login and run:

```
sudo reboot
```

I should see a log entry in /var/log/audit/audit.log with something like this:

```
type=CMD msg=audit(1484758210.821:630): user pid=2361 uid=101 auid=101 subj=system_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 exe="/sbin/reboot"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rule for it to audit.rules

```
-w /sbin/shutdown -p x -k power
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look into logs for that too if you can't or doesn't want to configure the audit rules:

```
sudo grep sudo /var/log/auth.log
```

Every sudo commands executed will be there, so you can find it by looking for 'reboot' or 'shutdown'.